# How to hide a partition on an MBR-formatted SD card?

Tags: partitioning, sd-card, mbr

I have an SD card with MBR, and want one of the partitions to be hidden. I have tried setting partition types to `0x1B` and `0x1C`, but Windows 10 seems to ignore the "hidden" flag.

Is there something I am missing, or is this normal Windows behavior and there is nothing I can do about it? Ideally, the solution would work with Windows 11 as well.

Note: Yes, I have to use MBR and FAT32. This is a limitation of licensing in the FAT implementation used.

Clarification: my goal, at the minimum, is to have those partitions not be automatically mounted.

Comment: Note: those "hidden" types are an OS/2 concept

Comment: @JaromandaX so, this being not a native Windows concept, are you suggesting this is unlikely to work?

Comment: well, it didn't, so I guess windows doesn't hide partitions

Comment: Shame. Whatever does the automounts on my Arch desktop actually doesn't automount them (not that they're hidden in any way).

Comment: common trick is to change signature in MBR 55AA to for example 55BB, and flip them back to allow mounting again.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen so, essentially, make the "hidden" MBR entry invalid? It's not the entire drive we want to not be automatically mounted, but rather only certain partitions. Since the visible partition is first, we could set the hidden entries to type `0x00`, although it does require a a non-trivial amount of work.

Comment: Ah, I didn't get that some needed hiding only. Is card used on different PC's or just one?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen the card is formatted by an embedded device (which we are developing), and might be used with any number of PCs. Or by users who do not have an administrative access on their PCs. Yes, I know the user can trash the partition layout, but in that case we can just format the card.